# mysql insert after trigger makes all insert queries to fail

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following table structure:
[image]

And this trigger:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `credits__after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `credits`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 
        UPDATE `clients`
            SET `clients`.`available_credits` =
                (SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `credits`
                    WHERE `client_id` = NEW.client_id )
            WHERE `clients`.`id` = NEW.client_id;
        
        UPDATE `credits`
            SET NEW.`remaining` =
                (SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `credits`
                    WHERE `client_id` = NEW.client_id );
    
    END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Every time I try to insert a new row I receive the following error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'credits' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I don't understand why it gives me this error. I also don't want to receive similar questions/answers because I've tried everything from SO in past two hours. I want a simple to comprehend explanation, and if possible a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: As much as I searched last night, the tiredness clearly kicked in. This morning I found another similar question and marked my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't [update the same table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

But you should have a separate table with

credit_values (credit_id,`available_credits`,`remaining`) and update this.

And when you need the information you simply join the table

You can only update the current row you are inserting with the sums

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `credits__after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `credits`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
 
        SET NEW.`available_credits` = (SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `credits` WHERE `client_id` = NEW.client_id );
        
        SET NEW.`remaining` = (SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `credits` WHERE `client_id` = NEW.client_id );
    
    END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

or as Akina pointed out as a single command without DELIMITER

```
CREATE TRIGGER `credits__after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `credits`
    FOR EACH ROW      
        SET NEW.`available_credits` = (SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `credits` WHERE `client_id` = NEW.client_id ),            
              NEW.`remaining` = (SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `credits` WHERE `client_id` = NEW.client_id);
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use multi-statement SET form - this allows to make the trigger single-statement and thus aviod DELIMITER reassign.

Comment: Your answer is good. Thank you for your time. Add this link to make it better: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Answer (score 1):

You try to update `credits` in your trigger. However, your trigger is defined on `credits`. Thus, the update on `credits` inside the trigger would cause the trigger to fire again - and again, and again, and again.

That's why MySQL forbids such constellations.

I think you'll need to rewrite the `UPDATE` of `credits` inside the trigger to directly modify the new entry.

Comment: It is `AFTER INSERT` therefore although your explanation is good, it does not apply to this case, only to case where is `AFTER UPDATE`. I translate my trigger like this: Insert something into credits; (trigger after insert) update last row;